# Inputting values into the variables without having to input the matrix all over again

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, linear-algebra

I'm practicing using LU decomposition on Mathematica. I am able to find the L & U matrices, specifically the variables. However, i find it tedious having to input the newly found values and form the L & U matrices. Is there a way on Mathematica to automatically allow the variables to adopt these newly found variables. I suspect I may have not explained myself clearly so i wrote down the code below.

```
a = {{1, -3, 2, -2}, {3, -2, 0, -1}, {2, 36, -28, 27}, {1, -3, 22, 5}}.

L = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {b, 1, 0, 0}, {c, d, 1, 0}, {e, f, g, 1}}

U = {{1, -3, 2, -2}, {0, h, i, j}, {0, 0, k, l}, {0, 0, 0, m}}
```

Then I did, `Solve[LU==a]`, and got:

```
(* {{b -> 3, c -> 2, d -> 6, e -> 1, f -> 0, g -> 5, h -> 7, i -> -6, 
    j -> 5, k -> 4, l -> 1, m -> 2}} *)
```

How do i then input these values into the original matrices without having to do it manually.

Thank you.

Comment: `{L, U} /. First @ Solve[(* stuff *)]`?

Comment: Also, you should be using `L.U` instead; `Dot[]` is the function intended for multiplying matrices in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

Using @J.M.'s comment, but spelled out in more detail:

```
a = {{1, -3, 2, -2}, {3, -2, 0, -1}, {2, 36, -28, 27}, {1, -3, 22, 5}};
L = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {b, 1, 0, 0}, {c, d, 1, 0}, {e, f, g, 1}};
U = {{1, -3, 2, -2}, {0, h, i, j}, {0, 0, k, l}, {0, 0, 0, m}};
result = {L, U} /. First @ Solve[L.U == a];
MatrixForm /@ result
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that matrix multiplication is done with `Dot` (`A.B`, where `A` and `B` are matrices). Somehow you got the answer, but the `Solve` statement you wrote was missing the dot.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `LUDecomposition` function in Mathematica:

```
a = {{1, -3, 2, -2}, {3, -2, 0, -1}, {2, 36, -28, 27}, {1, -3, 22, 5}};
n = Dimensions[a][[1]];
{LU, MP, MC} = LUDecomposition[a]
LU = First[LUDecomposition[a]]
L = LU * SparseArray[{i_, j_}/; j<i  -> 1, {n, n}] + IdentityMatrix[n]
U = LU * SparseArray[{i_, j_}/; j>=i -> 1, {n, n}]
L.U
```

Comment: The built-in function does partial pivoting. Granted, this is a must in applications, but the OP wants to do the usual Gaussian elimination sans pivoting, and there is no facility to switch pivoting off.